# ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’, ‘tidyr’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve a problem concerning the installation of the package on the Raspberry Pi 3 B+ **"finstr"** for a project. For the installation of **finstr**, I have to install another package named: "tidyverse".

Output on console:

```
c_local’, ‘default_missing.data.frame’, ‘default_missing.default’, ‘dim.tbl_cube’, ‘distinct.data.f [... truncated]
* DONE (ggplot2)
ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘tidyr’ are not available for package ‘modelr’
* removing ‘/root/R/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-library/3.5/modelr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’, ‘tidyr’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/root/R/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-library/3.5/tidyverse’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpQfqxqe/downloaded_packages’


Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Comment: What are you using to install the packages? Other words, from where and what did you type to install the packges?

Comment: I'm using R, the terminal on raspbian. I respectively wrote: R , install.packages("tidyverse")

Comment: And you're using R 3.5.3? That's a little old but should be doable... have you tried manually installing the dependencies that are called out, e.g., `install.packages("broom")`?

Comment: I'm using the R version 3.5.2. Yes, I tried. I tried also to update the version of R to try to check if it was outdated, but no. I can't really figure out a solution..

Comment: I mean, I'm using R 3.6.3 which was released in February 2020, your version 3.5.2 was released in Dec 2018, so it is a bit outdated. But `broom` says it depends on R >= 3.1, so you *should* be good either way, so I'm still confused by the error.

Comment: I haven't ever done this, but Microsoft maintains daily snapshots of CRAN packages at MRAN. You could try setting that as your repository and getting packages from just before 3.5.3 was released, like 2019-03-10.

Comment: Is there an easier solution?